# Do you have competitors?

Tags: competition, industry, business, professional-practice

Do you compete with someone or something (in the line of work that you do or in the business that you run)? Can you name your competitors (not meaning 'list them here', but whether the competitors have names)?

Competing against or with?
http://www.elew.com/competit.htm

Comment: If it doesn't seem like being sound -related, a similar question would be "Is sound design a competitive field of work?". That however is too broad for anyone to answer.

Comment:   As always it would be nice to hear why this question is downvoted. Isn't it a good industry/business/professional practice -related question (that at least I find interesting)?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but honestly thought this question was spam.

Comment: Downvoted, because it is spam.

Comment: (or at least looks like spam : Some general blabla, that would fit in anywhere, then click my link)

Comment:   @Markus it's a question, although perhaps slightly vague, because I find it difficult to formulate it better. "How it looks" is generally not a very good approach into assessing what something really is. I don't think I understand the meaning of the word "spam" in this context. Unless the question is inappropriate or the answer is self-evident and not worth discussing.

Comment: Sorry, misread the topic then - un-downvoted again. :) But how it "looks" is generally what we get, especially since it appears on a screen. There are many topics around the web, where a company advertises services this way, that do not are related with the forum, especially with the link below. 

Answer (score 1):

As far as the question of "competing with or against" there must be some of each, but this website strikes me as a great example of "competing with" in that by posting here, sound designers are helping each other out.  I am only starting out in this field but in my experience, it's a competitive field, but sound guys are by and large not competitive in nature.  Perhaps because of all the creative types, sound people are the least likely to be fame-seeking, so that takes a certain amount of ego out of the equation...

Well, I hate generalizing, but these are the thoughts that occurred to me when I read this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfectly legitimate question, and one we've all probably thought about at some point.

I can't say that I've worked in the field for long enough to have discovered a particular competitor as of yet, but that does not mean that I cannot be motivated by my future competitors. I've been told some version of the same magical list by many sources, including some on this forum:

There is always someone ...

- with a shorter drive to the gig than you
- who's willing to sleep less than you
- who knows more software than you
- who works quicker than you
- who's willing to work for less payment than you
- ...etc

Not the cheeriest messages, but they can be summed up in one sentence:  **You will always be a student in your craft.** Kinda tames the idea of competition for me, at least psychologically.

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: none of those reasons you list would be on the top of the list of a good director or producer... In my experience their mantra tends to be: what is BEST for the film

Comment: beware the race to the bottom, its a race where everyone loses

Comment: Great point. I certainly don't mean these statements like a speech I give to myself in the mirror each morning—I'm more saying that "competition", to me, is just another reason to always work to improve my skills, which will differ for each project without a doubt. Pardon my generalizations! 

Comment: all good/sorry for stating the obvious :)
